# Boost Tcp-Asio-Server Link failure using Qt on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt, boost

I have a very simple class, which I will send as Object via TCP using Asio by boost. I found [many examples on the Internet](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.serialization), but when I compile my code I get a Link Failure.

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>


void async_write(){
 std::ostringstream archive_stream;
 boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(archive_stream); // here it fails
 //....
}
```

I downloaded boost via macports.

My Qt project file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /opt/local/include
LIBS += -L/opt/local/lib
LIBS += -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_serialization-mt
```

Failure:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl::save(std::string const&)", referenced from:
>         void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, std::string const&) in tcpsession.o
>     "boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl::text_oarchive_impl(std::ostream&, unsigned int)", referenced from:
>         boost::archive::text_oarchive::text_oarchive(std::ostream&, unsigned int) in tcpsession.o
>     "boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive::~basic_text_oprimitive()", referenced from:
>         boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl::~text_oarchive_impl() in tcpsession.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make: *** [tcpserver] Error 1

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do simple Boost.Serialization (no asio) examples link for you? If not then likely because Serialization is not header only, so you have to build that library and link it to your program for using it.

Comment: Does `libboost_serialization-mt.a` actually exist on the linker path?

Comment: ok i use simple Boost Serialization. boost is building automatically after download from ports. i had include libboost_serialization-mt.a in qt creator in menu add external lib... but the problem is the same. the simple code boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(std::cout); could´t compile. What do i wrong?

Comment: in eclipse there are no problems...

Comment: Side note: Unless you're using the version of Qt that came with MacPorts, you're in for a world of hurt if you have a MacPorts qt4-mac package installed as well - as MacPorts headers will come before the headers for the Qt you use with your project.

Answer (score 0):

The standard reply would be "re-run qmake". It's even simpler to just delete the entire shadow build directory. One level up from the source of your project, there will be `build-...` folders. Delete all of them, and build again.

The simplest way to see whether your project file (the file with `LIBS +=` lines) is current, add something to it that's invalid (like a typo in the library name). If it still "builds" without showing the error directly aimed at your typo (a missing library), then you know that your build is not based on the current project file, and you should re-run qmake or delete the shadow build folder so that everything will be recreated there.

Comment: i deleted the build folders and made a "re-run qmake" but without success. i think the problem is by build boost for mac.what for option should i use with ./bootstrap and ./b2? i installed Qt-Creator and Boost on Win8 and there are no problems.I use Qt Creator with clang5.2.1 and my OS is osx 10.9.3.

Comment: @Max3579 Your boost comes from macports. You can always force a reinstallation from sources (`port -f -s install boost`). I have the same environment and it "just works", although I haven't tried the exact library you're having problems with.

Comment: thanks, i will try this... i use also the Signal/Slot concept from boost in Signal2.hpp. it works fine. i have the problem only with o/iarchive.hpp

Comment: @Max3579 You need to compare the arguments that the eclipse's build system (don't know much about it) passes to the linker with the ones that got put into the Makefile by qmake.